# Python pandas: Drop linhas com coluna duplicada e outra coluna com valor nulo

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Gostaria de fazer um drop nas linhas em que a coluna1 esteja duplicada e coluna2 seja valor nulo. Espero uma saída dessa forma

```
Col1  Col2
A     123
A     NaN
B     NaN
B     456
```

Saida

```
Col1  Col2
A     123
B     456
```

Tentei fazer mais ou menos assim: Será possível fazer esse tipo de Drop de linha

`df2 = df[df.duplicated('Col1')] and df[df['Col2'].isnull()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você fez está quase certo, faltou só um pequeno detalhe na função *duplicated*, e o condicionamento é feito junto:

```
df2 = df[df.duplicated('Col1', keep=False) & df['Col2'].isnull()]
```

Com o parâmetro *keep=False*, todos os duplicados são identificados.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) você pode utilizar o `dropna` do próprio pandas.

```
df = df.dropna(how='any')
```

ou modificando o existente, utilizando o `inplace`:

```
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
```

Além disso pode utilizar o parâmetro `axis` para selecionar se será excluída a linha ou coluna (0 ou 1, respectivamente).

Caso queira ser mais específico com qual coluna procurar utilize o parâmetro `subset`.

**Edit:**
Passei algum tempo tentando achar a solução com o NaN, porém sem sucesso. Mesmo utilizando o `pd.isnan()` para testar dá erro.

Se servir tem essa solução caso seja 0 no lugar de NaN.

```
df2 = df[~(df['Col1'].duplicated(False) & (df['Col2']=='0'))]
```

Comment: Eu não posso dropar todos os valores `null` da `Col2`, somente os que estão repetidos na `Col1`. Pois pode haver algum valor na `Col1` que não esteja duplicado e que seja `null` na `Col2`, estes eu desejo manter